# Rails - Getting "required parameter "client_secret" is missing" While using LinkedIn OmniAuth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise, linkedin-api

I was able to successfully implement a google login however, when trying to implement a login with LinkedIn I got the following error

Rails server logs

```rb
DEBUG -- omniauth: (linkedin) Callback phase initiated.
ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_request: A required parameter "client_secret" is missing
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"client_secret\" is missing"}
```

Gemfile.rb

```rb
gem 'devise', '~> 4.8'
gem 'omniauth', '~> 2.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 9.0'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', '~> 1.1'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 1.0'
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```rb
config.omniauth :linkedin, Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:api_id], Rails.application.credentials[:linkedin][:api_key]
```

I have placed correctly the credentials and I was able to access it within the console.
Kindly let me know if there are anything I missed ?

Thanks in advance.

I tried to downgrade the `omniauth` gem with no success.